# How to set search paths in Xcode for Eigen library

Tags: xcode, c++11, eigen

I am a new one who just gets started using Xcode. I have set the Header files path and the library files path, however, I cannot use the following coding.

```
using namespace Eigen;
```

I am not sure where the problem is. Thank you, everyone!
[image]

Comment: Have you included the `Eigen` header? Is it installed to the correct path?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The Xcode told me that it cannot find the Eigen, but when I include the <Eigen/Dense> the error disappeared. I do not know the reason for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directive `using namespace Eigen;` does not import the Eigen project into your code, but rather allows you to type `MatrixXd` instead of `Eigen::MatrixXd`. When you type `#include <Eigen/Dense>` you actually insert the file `Dense` into your code at that point, effectively importing the Eigen project into your directory. The file `Dense` is just a regular text file. On your computer it's located at `/usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.3.4/include/eigen3/Eigen/Dense`. Open it in a text editor to see what it looks like.